# How do you test multiple speakers in Ubuntu distributions?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, multimedia, speakers

I need to test the output of all speakers in a 5.1 system that runs 10.04 and 12.04 Ubuntu?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I use the command line:

List your sound card(s)

```
aplay -L
```

Test your speakers:

```
speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -l1 -twav
```

You may also specify a speaker

```
speaker-test -s left-front -twav
```

See also

- Ubuntu Community Wiki [Surround Sound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound)
- Manpage [speaker-test](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/speaker-test.1.html)

You can also test your speakers from the mixer (mixer varies with window manager)

In 12.04 use the "Test Sound" button

[image]

Comment: There is no Sound preferences "test speakers" button on 10.04 or 12.04. Speaker-test worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Yes, often command line tools are easier then finding the graphical tool. HUD should help.